# Getting a 500 error with the Domain Access module

Tags: domain-access, wsod, subsites

I use Drupal 7.22 with 7.x-3.9 Domain Access Module for multiple subdomains website.
Making of subdomains works fine, but I cannot access to subfolders on subdomains.

- example.com works
- example.com/admin/ works
- sub.example.com works
- sub.example.com/admin/ internal server error 500

This error is showing on every sub-folder (content) in every sub-domain. The root domain is fine with all content. Also, theme changing on sub-domains works fine. Am I missing something in documentation?

Answer (score 1):

To debug WSOD, you need info what exactly went wrong. There is a pretty neat [article about fixing them](http://drupal.org/node/482956) - try to follow it. Around step 2a you should pretty much know what you need to look for in documentation.